# React useState() - no css transitions? Just jumps to new class without animation/transition

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I've got a conditional class that is set with React's `useState()` Somehow the transition is not aimated. It just jumps to the new class values.

In the code example below I've tried to make it as clean as possible to my case. 
With the line 
`` className={`collapse my-navbar-collapse ${toggle ? "show" : ""}`} `` I set the class.

What am I missing here?

`header.js`

```
import React, { useState } from "react"
import "./header.sass"

const Header = () => {
  const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(false)

  return (
    <div className={'sticky-top'}>

      <button
        className="btn navbar-toggler"
        type="button"
        onClick={ () => setToggle(!toggle) }
      >
        button stuff
      </button>

      <div className={`collapse my-navbar-collapse ${toggle ? "show" : ""}`}>
        rest of my stuff
      </div>

    </div>

  )
}

export default Header
```

`header.sass`

```
.my-navbar-collapse
  background-color: red
  transition: all 2s ease
  height: 0

  &.show
    height: 100vh
```

(when it all works I'll change `transition: all 2s ease` from `all` to `height`. I just want to catch every for this test first :)

Comment: React part looks fine to me, I guess the problem is in CSS, what about class `collapse`? Have you checked it?

Comment: @Makan, yes, that was it. I changed my bootstrap approach to my own approach. But `collapse` and `show` (definitely the combination) where the issue. Removed the classes and added new unique ones and it animates fine. (not smooth, but it works) If you could add it as an answer I'll accept it. THANKS!

Comment: Nope, it is gone now. Wait, what? it worked for a few refreshed. And now not :) :) A couple of undo's and redo's and I can't find it... Guess it was not the `collapse` class

Comment: You might want to use chrome's computed properties devtool on the div in question, see if something is overriding the transition that you are setting. You can also put !important after the transition and see if that fixes it.

Comment: @Tim It happens :)

Comment: @ZacharyHaber, it was the highest in hierarchy already. But also with the `!important` no difference. But I think something else is wrong. I've added `import { CSSTransition } from "react-transition-group"` to the element and also this only fires only now and then. Not every refresh...

Comment: What do you guys think about this. Seems to be stable during the last few tests:```.my-navbar-collapse
  background-color: red
  height: 0
  overflow: hidden

  &.my-show-key
    animation: 1s keyHeight
    height: 100vh

  @keyframes keyHeight
    0%
      height: 0

    100%
      height: 100vh```

Comment: Wow, that doesn't look good. I mean using css's `@keyframes`

Comment: :) :) using `@keyframes` in react coponents css is a big no no :) :) it fires the animations every render

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't have any issues with the height transition as you can see from this demo.

However, it looks like you were forgetting `overflow: hidden` in your css. You need this because by default css tries to make sure nothing is lost even when that messes up stylings, so in order for the "rest of my stuff" text to be hidden when your navbar is collapsed, you need to make sure to hide it.

It looks like the issue is in the collapse class. Bootstrap's transitions.css adds `display: none` via that class. If there's not a display, then the css can't transition properly. Hence the issue.

The example now has 2 buttons, one triggers the div that has the collapse class, the other div doesn't have it.

```js
const Header = () => {
  const [toggle, setToggle] = React.useState(false);
  const [toggle2, setToggle2] = React.useState(false);
  return (
    <div className={'sticky-top'}>
      <button
        className="btn navbar-toggler"
        type="button"
        onClick={() => setToggle(!toggle)}
      >
        button stuff - collapse
      </button>

      <div className={`collapse my-navbar-collapse ${toggle ? 'show' : ''}`}>
        rest of my stuff
      </div>
      <button
        className="btn navbar-toggler"
        type="button"
        onClick={() => setToggle2(!toggle2)}
      >
        button stuff - no collapse
      </button>

      <div className={`my-navbar-collapse ${toggle2 ? 'show' : ''}`}>
        rest of my stuff
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
ReactDOM.render(<Header />, document.querySelector('#root'));
```

```css
.my-navbar-collapse {
  background-color: red;
  transition: height 2s ease;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.my-navbar-collapse.show {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the example!  As @Makan mentioned, the error was in the combination of bootstrap's `collapse` class and my code. But the `overflow` definitely helps :)

Comment: Looks like it was the bootstrap's collapse class. It was adding `display: none`

Comment: @Tim If you haven't seen this since I updated it, you should be able to just make sure your div doesn't have display: none

Comment: Thanks, seems to be something else with react. I've swapped out all classNames to make sure it doesn't interfere with something else. But no succes. It only works sometimes. And sometimes not. Just after refreshing the page. without changing the code. It is wrapped inside a `useContext()` hook.

Comment: It sounds like something else is an issue there, as demonstrated, the base part you gave us already works. I might suggest making a reproducible example of it not working in a code-sandbox or the like and setting up a new question for it. It might also give you insight to what's going wrong if you start with the working example and add until it stops.

Comment: Alright, I finally figured it out. In the real code the `my-navbar-collapse` div was called by `<myNavbarCollapse/>` from a `constant` from within `<Header/>` . Moving the code out of this const and just right into the return of Header it worked. I cannot reproduce it here in a snippet. So I'm guessing the problem lays deeper than just that. But, in my case it was the solution... Wierd.